Excel Vstack Formula with OFFset when data is empty
I'm trying to combine a few datasets together using VStack and Offset
Vstack because the data is in different areas, and Offset because the data in the range varies (sometimes even being empty)
=VSTACK(OFFSET( B2,0,0,COUNTA(B2:B4),2),OFFSET( E2,0,0,COUNTA(E2:E4),2))

This is my formula (simplified for my query here and so I don't have to show sensitive data

As you can see from screenshot it works fine when there is data in the ranges, but if the range happens to be empty (which is possible with my real life data)

The Formula errors out (I know it's because my 2nd offset is also returning an error) I've tried using iferror() to cater for this
And even some if statements within but I can't seem to get around this, end up with a row of #N/A which I don't won't
Image below with some options I've tried


Instead the empty string use {"",""} but an empty row will be there.

ooh, thanks that's looks to be working.
and I can wrap the whole thing in a filter to exclude empty rows

One could try using the following formula, which uses TRIMRANGE() features as well as VSTACK() function wrapped within UNIQUE(), the formulas doesn't uses any volatile functions :


=UNIQUE(VSTACK(B.:.C,E.:.F))


This should still work, if one of the data ranges is empty:


Here are some other alternatives, converting the ranges into Structured References aka Tables then one of the following can be used as well:
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL((Table1,Table2),1),2)


Or,
=LET(
     a, VSTACK(Table1,Table2),
     FILTER(a,BYROW(a<>"",AND)))



Hi, Thanks for taking a look, but that doesn't fix my issue if one of my data ranges is empty

@MichaelLiew have you tried to follow the screenshots and did you really try before commenting, whereas I see it seems to be working and not volatile as well, using volatile are highly not recommended!

They don't seem to work for me, I don't have trimrange.
I'm using office 365. but they seem to error for me

Using your examples though gave me some ideas to try and I managed to get it working using this
=LET(x,VSTACK(B2:C4,E2:F4),FILTER(x,CHOOSECOLS(x,1)<>""))

=LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(DROP(B:F,1),1),2),SORTBY(w,ISEVEN(SEQUENCE(ROWS(w)))))
w gets your data but first line is 1st from The 1st range and second line from 2nd followed by 2nd line from 1st and 2nd line from 2nd, etc.
Sorting them by the sequence of rows being even gives you the original order.
If you expand it to more columns, you could use something like:
=LET(d,B:I,SORTBY(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(DROP(d,1),1),2),TOCOL(IFS(d,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(d))),2)))
But whole column referencing is not recommended. (See trimrange referencing as posted by Mayukhbeing in Beta still).
